# Why window.addEventListener does not work?

Tags: javascript

On the window.onload event, I would like a function to be called. 
If I define it as given below, the function does not get called.

```
try {
    window.addEventListener("load", initialiseTable, false);
} catch(e) {
    window.onload = initialiseTable;
}

var initialiseTable = function () {
    console.log("hello world!!");
};
```

but if I change the function declaration to

```
function initialiseTable() {
    console.log("hello world!!");};
```

it works, any idea?

Comment: I'd say the problem is the execution order as `initialiseTable` is used to previous to declaration

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#function_oddities

Comment: Late comment, but this is why you should please provide info rather than linking to it. That developer.mozilla.org link is no good anymore, no clue what it used to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you using `var x = function(){}` to declare functions, it should be declare before you call the function.

By `function x (){}`, `x` will exist in current scope, no matter how later it declare. Because such **side effect**, the `var x = function(){}` are more recommended. For example:

```
var user = 'alien';
if( user == 'alien') {
    function salute () { console.log("Welcome to Earth!"); }
} else {
    function salute (){ console.log("Good day!"); }
}
```

The `salute()` will print `Good day!` anyway, even though it not we want at all.

Comment: you are star, thanks!!

Comment: `load` wasn't working even with the function declaration. I was using jQuery, so replaced the code with `$(window).on('load', function(){ loadMethod(); }); and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the function before.

```
var initialiseTable = function () {
    console.log("hello world!!");
};
try {
    window.addEventListener("load", initialiseTable, false);
} catch(e) {
    window.onload = initialiseTable;
}
```

For more information about declaring a function read this: 
[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the function **initialiseTable** to the first position, eg:

```
var initialiseTable = function (){ /*[...]*/ }
```

After continue calling.

Answer (score 1):

Since you come from C#, the difference is a lot like:

```
class A {
    public int method2() {
        //I can call method1 even though it *declared* later below
        int a = method1(); 
    }

    public int method1() {

    }
}
```

vs

```
class B {
    public int method2() {
        bool a = method1(3); //I can't call it because it is *assigned* later below.
                         //In fact I cannot even compile it 
        Func<int, bool> method1 = x => x == 3;
    }
}
```

You may notice the difference in javascript, if you look at:

```
function a() {

}
```

There is no assignment anywhere.

Where as with `var a = function(){}` there is obviously assignment and it is similar to the latter C# example.

Answer (score 0):

Function declaration should always precede its call.

At this line:-

```
window.addEventListener("load", initialiseTable, false);
```

initialiseTable is not known so it should be placed after function definition.
Actually  function statement causes its identifier to be bound before anything in its code-block* is executed.Function declarations loads before any code is executed.  It differs from the function expression which is evaluated in normal top-down order. Function expressions loads only when the interpreter reaches that line of code. so if you use:-

```
var initialiseTable = function () {
    console.log("hello world!!");
};
```

it won't work but this works:-

```
function initialiseTable() {
    console.log("hello world!!");};
```